# How do I obtain Django's user password reset URL within Python (i.e., not within a template)

Tags: python, django

I am generating a variable text in Python where I need to inject the URL for the user to navigate to after they requested password reset. I.e., I am building a string for content of an email and thus cannot use the standard template language `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`

What I have so far is:

```
def myFunction(toEmail_):
  #-- find user to send the email to
  user = User.objects.get(email=toEmail_)

  #-- build email text
  resetUrl = "????" #TODO: WHAT TO PUT IN HERE?
  emailText = "Hi, please reset your password on this url {}".format(resetUrl)
  
  #-- send email with the text
  ...
```

How do I obtain this reset url in Python?

Comment: You certainly can use the template language to create an email.  It just converts one string into another string.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse). It takes the same parameters that you pass the `{% url %}` templatetag.

For your example, it would become:

```
reset_url = reverse('password_reset_confirm', kwargs={'uidb64': uid, 'token': token})
```

Comment: however, how do I get uid and token in a view class, just from request or from the user object?

Comment: There's not enough information in your post to be able to answer that question. If the variables are available in the context of the page, they are likely available in the corresponding view somewhere.